# Take property within an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, ngx-datatable

I have ngx-datatable that receive an array of arrays as the following:

```
{0: Array(1)
 0:
   alert: null
   areEquals: true
   key: "Payment Date"
   order: 0
   readOnly: false
   subCollection: null
   valueMaster: "06/11/2020 00:00:00"
   valueSlave: "06/11/2020 00:00:00"
   __proto__: Object
   length: 1
   __proto__: Array(0)},
  { 1: Array(1)
    0:
      alert: null
      areEquals: true
      key: "Payment Date"
      order: 0
      readOnly: false
      subCollection: null
      valueMaster: "08/02/2021 00:00:00"
      valueSlave: "08/02/2021 00:00:00"
      __proto__: Object
      length: 1
      __proto__: Array(0)
    }
```

I'm trying to create a table using the valueMaster and valueSlave properties, which are inside array 0, which is present in all arrays. What am I doing so far:

```
<ngx-datatable
              class='table mt-0 table-hover table-stripped' 
              [rows]="paymentFlow" 
              [messages]="''" 
              [columnMode]="'force'" 
              [sorts]="[{prop: propSort, dir: 'asc'}]" 
              [rowHeight]="getRowHeight">
              
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Base Gai" prop="valueMaster">              
                <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                  {{value}}         
                </ng-template>
              </ngx-datatable-column>

              <ngx-datatable-column name="Cln" prop="valueSlave">
                <ng-template let-value="value">
                  {{value}}          
                </ng-template>
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              </ngx-datatable>
```

However the table returns empty, I believe why I have to do a previous iteration, to get exactly [0], which is where the properties are. Could someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays basically and each item in the array has length 1 for sure, correct? So in the cell templates your row is basically an array, not an object, and you need to access `row[0].valueMaster` or `row[0].valueSlave`, depending on the column.

You can do that by defining the templates like this:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Value master">
    <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{row[0].valueMaster}}
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>

<ngx-datatable-column name="Value slave">
    <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{row[0].valueSlave}}
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Be aware that these columns cannot be sortable. The sort method on the ngx-datatable implies that the prop should be a direct property of an object, so the fact that you are accesing properties in an array won't allow you to sort.

I propose to modify your structure after fetching the data by adding to the rows only the first item of each array and then use the templates like they are in your initial attempt, this if you don't need other elements of the arrays in other part of your table.

Assuming the result of your GET request is:

```
  data = [
    [
      {
        alert: null,
        areEquals: true,
        key: "Payment Date",
        order: 0,
        readOnly: false,
        subCollection: null,
        valueMaster: "06/11/2020 00:00:00",
        valueSlave: "06/11/2020 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        alert: null,
        areEquals: true,
        key: "Payment Date",
        order: 0,
        readOnly: false,
        subCollection: null,
        valueMaster: "08/02/2021 00:00:00",
        valueSlave: "08/02/2021 00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  ];
```

Construct your `rows` array like this: `this.rows = this.data.map(item => item[0]);` and use the templates you provided, which will support sorting by `valueMaster` and `valueSlave` properties.